# Dynamically creating multiple label and assigning values to it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic-controls

I want to create multiple label dynamically and assign values to it,

I have created multiple radio button list and assigned values to it but when i use the same for label only one label control appears and the label takes the last value in the loop as text.

What i have tried is

```
Dim table1 As New HtmlTable
For j As Integer = 0 To 2  
    Dim row As New HtmlTableRow()

    Dim cell1 As New HtmlTableCell()
    Dim cell2 As New HtmlTableCell()

    Dim rbl As New RadioButtonList()
    Dim lbl1 As New Label


   For RowIndex As Integer = 0 To 2
        rbl.ID = RowIndex
        rbl.Items.Add(DataSet columnvalues)

        lbl1.ID = Convert.ToInt32(j) ' The problem is in this two line
        lbl1.Text = (DataSet label values)
   Next

    cell1.Controls.Add(rbl)
    cell2.Controls.Add(lbl1)


    row.Cells.Add(cell1)
    row.Cells.Add(cell2)

   table1.Rows.Add(row)

Next
ControlsPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(table1)
```

Comment: I am confused. Where did you declare lbl1? And you are adding only tle last label. The line `cell2.Controls.Add(lbl1)`should be inside de `RowIndex`loop, no?

Comment: sorry lbl is lbl1, now i have changed it

Comment: I have changed my comment. I think it solves your problem. But you need also put the command `New Label` inside the loop.

Comment: @Nizam ill check that and say, whether it works or not.. Thank you for your idea

Answer (score 1):

Change the loop to

```
   For RowIndex As Integer = 0 To 2
        rbl.ID = RowIndex
        rbl.Items.Add(DataSet columnvalues)
        Dim lbl1 As New Label
        lbl1.ID = Convert.ToInt32(j) ' The problem is in this two line
        lbl1.Text = (DataSet label values)
        cell2.Controls.Add(lbl1)
        cell2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"))
   Next
```

Otherwise you are only creating one label with the last values.

The difference is that you have only one `RadioButtonList` and you are adding N items. But you have to create N labels in this case.

Comment: Your code works fine but there is a problem, the value of the label must appear next to each radio button list item

Comment: You will need to add a literal to placeholder, just like suggested by Vignesh Kumar in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Label with RadioButton List Item so Use **RowIndex** for Label ID not **J**

Try like this

```
 Dim table1 As New HtmlTable
        For j As Integer = 0 To 2
            Dim row As New HtmlTableRow()
            Dim cell1 As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim cell2 As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim rbl As New RadioButtonList()
            For RowIndex As Integer = 0 To 2
                rbl.ID = RowIndex
                rbl.Items.Add("Hi")
                Dim lbl1 As New Label()
                lbl1.ID = "Hi" + RowIndex.ToString
                lbl1.Text = "hello"
                lbl1.Height = "25"
                cell2.Controls.Add(lbl1)

               ' Add This
                cell2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"))
            Next
            cell1.Controls.Add(rbl)
            row.Cells.Add(cell1)
            row.Cells.Add(cell2)
            table1.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table1)
```

This line will give you the line break between Controls

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"))
```

Comment: Your code works fine but there is a problem, the value of the label must appear next to each radio button list item

Comment: I think the radio button list should be out of the RowIndex loop. Otherwise you are creating N lists of 1 element instead of 1 list with N elements.

Comment: I am not sure there will be problem to use the same ID. Since we are in the server side, they will each one receive a different ID on client side. I need to check this.

Comment: None, I was just saying that I think there is no need to use different IDs